# Where i can find Magento advance cms admin html file

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I have downloaded the advance cms extension all working fine . I need to edit the admin panel listing page.
Does any one has idea where i can find the advance cms admin panel html file ?

Comment: If there is no html file check module block files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all backend html files (actually phtml files) can be found in app/design/adminhtml/...

You could also mean admin grid? then look in your module folder in Block folder. Then search for Grid.php files. One of them should be the one you look for. I'm not sure if you would like to add/remove columns, but If you do, check this tutorial here on how to edit your grid: inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-extend-magento-order-grid

Comment: yes it has to be there .. i have checked the entire folder of adminhtml but could not found